# How to add a scrollbar to accordion in PrimeNG?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, accordion, primeng

I have an issue when expanding panels within my accordion in my Angular App. Basically if I expand a panel this is expanding and **going over** the footer of my application so I was thinking on adding a scrollbar to the accordion so it doesn't go over the footer anymore but I'm not sure where to start. Does anyone know how to add a scrollBar to accordion ? My guess is that I will need to put the accordion in a container and then add a scrollbar ? 
Here's my code and would like to add a scrollbar.

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/YbRW0ZHAkA9j2h6i8p3z?p=preview)

```
<p-accordion [activeIndex]="index">
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
   Content 1
</p-accordionTab>
<p-accordionTab *ngIf="true" header="Header 2">
   Content 2
</p-accordionTab>
<p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
  Content 3
</p-accordionTab>
```

Here are two images on what happens with my footer when a panel gets expanded:

***1) BEFORE Expanding Panel***

[image]

***2) AFTER Expanding Panel***

[image]

Comment: Your plunker doesn't have a footer. Did you save?

Comment: Yes you are right, that was just a sample of multiple panels within an accordion. Do you know how to add a scrollBar to the accordion?

Comment: Not sure to understand. Do you want your accordion to have a fixed height ?

Comment: @Antikhippe yes a fixed height so it does overlap footer when expanding a panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these CSS properties to the `p-accordion` element :

```
height: 275px;
display: block;
overflow: scroll;
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KqgGGXBuGRAV0b8C4NvA?p=preview)

Comment: Ok, can you update the Plunker to add the footer so that I can reproduce this problem please ?

Comment: the application is pretty big and not sure if I'll be able to add the footer on the plunker example

Comment: Ok but I don't know how you created your footer. I edited my Plunker to add a footer, do you reproduce the problem on it ?